# Bundle install foundation-icons-sass-rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, bundler

I'm having an issue with foundation-icons-sass-rails

When i bundle install, it installs without an issue.

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.4.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.4
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.4
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.4
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.4
Using activemodel 4.1.4
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.4
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.4
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.3.0
Using sass 3.2.19
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.4
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Installing foundation-icons-sass-rails 3.0.0
Using foundation-rails 5.4.3.0
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using kaminari 0.16.1
Using mysql2 0.3.16
Using polyamorous 1.1.0
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using rails 4.1.4
Using ransack 1.3.0
Using spring 1.1.3
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.3.0
Using uglifier 2.5.3
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

And this is the output from trying to start rails console

```
$ rails c
Could not find foundation-icons-sass-rails-3.0.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm using rvm with gemsets. 
Ruby 2.1.2

I've tried deleting gemset and all gems, then re-installing etc. and nothing works. Any ideas on this would be amazing, this is killing me!

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your `.bundle/config` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `bin/spring stop` to force your application to re-initialize.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't believe it was something so simple!